# Port forwarding, TP link TL-WR740N

Tags: router, port-forwarding, hosting

my router model is TL-WR740N and it is from TP link, I am trying to portforward few ports to host a server,but its not working. I turned firewall off to try it, but its not working, I did follow the guide from " Portforward.com " and downloaded their app...Could you help me a bit please? i am trying to figure this out for like 2-3 hours at least, also, my IPv4 is different in CMD ipconfig and on "whats my ip adress " website.
I here is shared link of my google drive, where i uploaded all screenshots of TP link setup, CMD ip config and the app i used. Thank you for help and your time
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Q3kEi0Z0dJUzJBWHNROVhwZUE

Comment: can you post the output of ports listening on 192.158.0.50? The open port check will work only if the port forwarded on your router is really listening.

Comment: How can i do find that?

Comment: on windows: open command prompt and post the output of `netstat -an | findstr "LISTEN"` and it has to list the ports you are interested in to connect from outside your local network.

Comment: Those all are ports I am listeting, can i only port forward those? http://prntscr.com/ep9m44

Comment: You can port forward any port, but it will work only if the IP you are port forwarding to listens to the port you are forwarding to. What do you want to achieve with port forwarding?

Comment: I want to be able to host a server in the game called "Ark" for me and my friends, What does mean that thing about listening i screened you?

Comment: You should really first familiarize yourself with networking concepts and understand what is what and how to achieve it. You posted a list of open ports on your computer, meaning your computer is listening on those ports for incoming traffic. Another problem could be if you are behind a NATted IP. In that case you have to ask your ISP to port forward ports to your external IP which they might or might not do. I would suggest you ask a friend who knows those things to check and set it up for you.

Comment: damn it...ill ask friends,maybe so one understands, ill give a shot ISP,ill try to call him

Answer (score 0):

You must order the additional service "Fixed IP". Without this internet provider blocks the incoming requests.
For example [ISP site](https://www.o2.cz/osobni/203291-internet/40771-pevna_ip_adresa.html).

Then, you can enable remote access to the web interface of the router. And try to connect to the router via a global address and not through local (192.168.0.50).

When it will be possible then you can configure port forwarding and everything else.

Comment: Your  need to edit your answer in order to explain and give more information

Comment: 62.168.34.137 this site cannot  be reached

Comment: @RostikCZE  you need to contact the ISP.

Comment: So,the problem is that my ISP doesnt allow me to portforward and that is whole problem? Id like to know this, because hell, i am trying to setup my own ARK server for like 5 hours and theres a problem and I dont know which,thats the worst part of it,its not easy to fix something,if i dont know what it is

Comment: @RostikCZE  port forward work but only one direction from your server to a remote client. When client try to connect to your server or you check open port by Portforward.com incoming request is reduce by the firewall of ISP.

Comment: understood,tommorow i will call the ISP and ask about it,thank you for all your time and info,very much appreciated, because compared to you,i am total PC pleb, you saved me hours of work

Comment: @RostikCZE On a site your ISP or in your personal account you can find information or service available to you.

Comment: What am I looking for? The name